# Get mariadb to handle date searches like mysql (e.g. with date like 2020-12-32)

Tags: datetime, mariadb

With mysql it is possible to search for a full month with a sql query like

```
select * from table where date_created >= '2020-12-01' and date_created <= '2020-12-32'
```

column date_created is datetime type.
This does not work with mariadb. I know that the date 2020-12-32 is invalid. But is it possible to get this working with mariadb?

Comment: "*This does not work with mariadb*" and rightfully so. Every self-respecting database will reject that. What's wrong with writing `>= '2020-12-01' and date_create < '2021-01-01'`?

Comment: It is a 15 years old php application with more than a million lines of code producing this kind of code on several places. Since it works with variables and calculation it is hard to find all the places this ugly approach is using. So it would be great to get this also working with mariadb, so I havent to change the old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make this statement work without modifying either your code or your table definition:

Since the `date_created` is defined as date type, the strings in the where clause will be converted to date before doing comparison. The date "2020-12-32" is invalid and will be converted to "0000-00-00" which means the where condition becomes `WHERE date_created > 2020-12-01 and date_created < 0000-00-00`:  therefore the statement will not return any rows.

However it is interesting that the optimizer doesn't figure out an impossible WHERE condition and is doing a scan.